# Chain Rule with for composition of scalar and multivariable functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, chain-rule

Suppose I have the following function $f(\bf x)= \bf a^\top \log (\bf A \bf x )$, where $\bf x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\bf A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. The $\log$ function is entry wise.
I am considering $f(\cdot)$ to be the composition of three functions: the linear function $g(\bf y)= \bf a^\top \bf y$, the function $y(\bf z)= \log (\bf z)$ and the function $z(\bf x)= \bf A \bf x$.

So I have $f(\bf x)= g(y(z(x)))$. Here I have composition of scalar and multivariable functions, so the general chain rule for scalar function does not hold in general (also the order of the terms changes when vectors are involved). How to properly compute the gradient and the Hessian of such a function? How to handle the entry-wise $\log$ in the chain rule?

Thank you.

Comment: use the chain rule for multivariate functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{enclose}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\def\o#1{\operatorname{#1}}\def\D{\o{Diag}}$
Take an ordinary *scalar* function $\phi(s)$ and its derivative
$\phi′(s)=\frac{d\phi}{ds}$ and apply them element-wise to a vector argument $v$ to generate the associated *vector* functions
$$h=\phi(v),\qquad h'=\phi'(v)$$
The differential of such a vector function can expressed using an elementwise $(\odot)$ product or better yet, a diagonal matrix
$$\eqalign{
dh &= h'\odot dv \;=\; \D(h')\,dv\\
}$$
Setting $\;h=\log(v),\;v=Ax,\;V=\D(v)\;$ this becomes
$$\eqalign{
dh = d\log(v)
 &= V^{-1}dv\;=\; V^{-1}A\,dx \\
}$$
Now we're ready to calculate the differential and gradient of the current function.
$$\eqalign{
f &= a:h \\
df &= a:dh \\
  &= a:V^{-1}A\,dx \\
  &= A^TV^{-1}a:dx \\
\p{f}{x} &= A^TV^{-1}a \;=\; g\qquad({\rm gradient}) \\
}$$
The hessian is the gradient of the gradient,
so start the calculation with the differential of $g$.
$$\eqalign{
dg &= A^T\color{red}{dV^{-1}}a \\
  &= A^T\color{red}{(-V^{-1}dV\,V^{-1})}a \\
  &= -A^TV^{-2}dV\,a \\
  &= -A^TV^{-2}\D(a)\;dv \\
  &= -A^TV^{-2}\D(a)\,A\;dx \\
\p{g}{x} &= -A^TV^{-2}\D(a)\,A \;=\; H\qquad({\rm hessian}) \\
}$$

---

A colon has been used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(A^TB) \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \\
}$$
This definition can also be applied to vectors by treating them as rectangular matrices (set $n=1$) in which case it is equal to the standard dot product.

The terms in a Frobenius product can be rearranged in a number of ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:C \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
CA:B &= A:C^TB \;=\; C:BA^T \\
}$$
due to the properties of the underlying trace function.

Some of the steps in the derivation used certain properties of diagonal matrices. In terms of the vectors {$a,b$} these properties can be written as
$$\eqalign{
\D(a)\cdot\D(b) &= \D(b)\cdot\D(a) \\
\D(a)\cdot b &= \D(b)\cdot a \\
}$$

Finally, one of the comments asked about the product rule for differentials. Here is the general rule for arbitrary tensors {$S,T$} and *any* product {$\star$} with which they are dimensionally compatible.
$$\eqalign{
d(S\star T) &= (S+dS)\star(T+dT) \;-\; S\star T \\
 &= \big(S\star T +S\star dT +dS\star T +dS\star dT\big) \;-\; S\star T \\
 &= S\star dT + dS\star T + (\enclose{horizontalstrike}{dS\star dT}) \\
 &= S\star dT + dS\star T \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you greg. How do you go from the 2nd equality to the 3rd and 4th? And how do you go from $f$ to $df$ as you do from the 1st to the 2nd equation?

Comment: And another question: can we say that $f^\prime$ is a sort of ``element-wise derivative'' with respect to the variable $x$? Because I guess it cannot be defined as the gradient, due to the fact we have a vector-valued function.

Comment: @Albus I've reworked the answer to clarify the meaning of the symbol $h'$ as the vector resulting from the element-wise application of a scalar function to a vector argument, where the function happens to be the derivative of another scalar function.

Comment: Thank you @greg. It is a trivial question, but how do you conclude that $dv=d Ax= A dx$? Likewise why from $f=a:h$ you can directly write $df= a:dh$? I mean, to find the differential should not you ``prove'' beforehand what is the linear part in the Taylor expansion?

Comment: And to find the Hessian, should I perturb the $dh$ or directly the $dx$?

Comment: Where did you use the product rule for differential? I still don't see this steps according to the rule you mentioned $dv=d(Ax)=Adx$. In that case should be $dv= Adx + dAx$ More in general, do the differential rule for scalar functions hold also for vector functions? For instance we usually perturb the argument of the function with a scalar and try to see the component that varies linearly in the perturbation. That is the gradient. Is it still valid?

Comment: Exactly, except $dA=0$ because $A$ is a **constant** in this particular problem, so it was omitted. The given rule applies to any tensor, therefore it can be applied to combinations of scalars, vectors, matrices, and beyond (i.e. 3rd/4th order tensors) for which the $(\star)$ product makes sense.

Comment: Ok, so to clarify. When we have a function $f(x)$ that can be expressed as the composition of an arbitrary number of functions $f(h(g(x)))$, when we perturb it to find its differential, according to your definition is it equivalent to perturb it as $f(x+dx)$ or $f(h+dh)$? 
And where these general rules can be found? Again in Magnus?